# Animation Doesn't Have My Texture Paint in Blender

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render an animation in blender but my texture paint seems to do nothing. And it's weird because when I go back into Texture Paint everything is still there.
I looked it up and didn't find anything useful, I tried repainting everything, and changing the shading but none of it worked.

Edit: It seems that it renders with the 4th viewport shading option (the shaded circle) and when I turn that on it looks exactly the same. So how do I render it in the 2nd one (the full circle)

Edit 2: It seems that I only used the Base Color Texture for the door (the gray piece in the back) and I need to redo the texture painting all with Base Color for the texture.

My Texture Paint:
[image: My Texture Paint]

My Blender Render:
[image]

My Blender File: [image]

Comment: Hello could you please share the object itself? Don't forget to pack the images (File > External Data > Pack Resources)

Comment: I'm not sure where you've got your information from for working in Blender, but it looks as if you're trying to texture and render your scene in Viewport Shading mode (the full white orb).  That view is supposed to be used for modelling, not for texturing and rendering! Have a read through the section in the Blender manual to show what each mode is used for. You should also research some of the thousands of YT videos which cover materials and texture painting in Blender.

Comment: Yes you are probably confusing some modes, in Solid mode by default you'll only see the painting if you are in Texture Paint, otherwise your objects will look grey, so switch to another mode to see the result

Comment: I meant to include the [link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html) to the relevent section of Blender's manual in my previous comment.

Comment: Wow, thanks everyone for the help, I'll be sure to read through that manual, I am pretty new to this stuff